# Filling holes in intraday time series

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

I have this time series (1 minute time frame)

```
structure(list(V1 = c("01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", 
"01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", 
"01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", 
"01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", 
"01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", 
"01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "01/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", "02/04/2007", 
"02/04/2007", "02/04/2007"), V2 = c("23:01", "23:03", "23:04", 
"23:05", "23:06", "23:07", "23:08", "23:09", "23:14", "23:15", 
"23:17", "23:19", "23:20", "23:25", "23:26", "23:28", "23:29", 
"23:31", "23:32", "23:34", "23:39", "23:43", "23:45", "23:46", 
"23:55", "23:56", "00:02", "00:03", "00:06", "00:09", "00:13", 
"00:15", "00:16", "00:17", "00:18", "00:20", "00:22", "00:23", 
"00:33", "00:41", "00:42", "00:43", "00:47", "00:48", "00:50", 
"00:51", "00:55", "00:56", "00:59", "01:00", "01:01", "01:02", 
"01:04", "01:05", "01:07", "01:09", "01:11", "01:12", "01:18", 
"01:19", "01:20", "01:21", "01:22", "01:26", "01:27", "01:28", 
"01:30", "01:32", "01:35", "01:40", "01:41", "01:44", "01:46", 
"01:47", "01:51", "02:07", "02:09", "02:11", "02:13", "02:15", 
"02:21", "02:22", "02:23", "02:24", "02:28", "02:30", "02:32", 
"02:39", "02:45", "03:14", "03:17", "03:22", "03:28", "03:32", 
"04:21", "04:28", "04:34", "04:39", "04:45", "04:47"), V3 = c(1791, 
1790.5, 1790.25, 1789.5, 1790, 1790.5, 1790.25, 1790, 1789.75, 
1789.25, 1789.25, 1788.75, 1789, 1789.25, 1789.25, 1789.5, 1790.25, 
1790.75, 1791, 1791.5, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1790.75, 1791.5, 1791, 
1790.75, 1790, 1790, 1789.75, 1789.75, 1789.5, 1789.75, 1790, 
1790.5, 1790.75, 1791, 1791, 1791, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1791, 
1791, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 
1791, 1792, 1792, 1792, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1793, 1793.25, 1793, 
1793, 1793.25, 1793.75, 1793.75, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793, 1793.25, 
1793.5, 1793.5, 1792.75, 1793.25, 1793, 1793, 1792.5, 1793.25, 
1793.5, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.5, 1792.5, 1793, 1793, 
1792.75, 1793.25, 1792.25, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1792.5, 
1792.75, 1793, 1793.25, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793.25, 1793.25, 1793
), V4 = c(1791, 1790.5, 1790.25, 1790.25, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1790.25, 
1790, 1789.75, 1789.25, 1789.25, 1788.75, 1789, 1789.25, 1789.5, 
1790, 1790.25, 1791, 1791.25, 1792, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1790.75, 
1791.5, 1791.25, 1790.75, 1790.25, 1790, 1789.75, 1789.75, 1789.75, 
1789.75, 1790.25, 1790.5, 1791.25, 1791, 1791, 1791, 1790.5, 
1790.5, 1790.5, 1791, 1791, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 
1791.25, 1791.75, 1791.25, 1792.5, 1792, 1792, 1792, 1793, 1792.75, 
1793.25, 1793.25, 1793, 1793.25, 1793.75, 1794, 1793.75, 1793.5, 
1793.5, 1793, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1792.75, 1793.25, 1793, 
1793, 1792.5, 1793.75, 1793.5, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1793, 
1792.5, 1792.5, 1793, 1793, 1792.75, 1793.75, 1792.25, 1792.5, 
1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1793.25, 1793.25, 1793.5, 
1793.5, 1793.25, 1793.25, 1793), V5 = c(1790.75, 1789.75, 1790.25, 
1789.5, 1790, 1790.5, 1790.25, 1790, 1789.75, 1788.75, 1789, 
1788.75, 1788.75, 1789.25, 1789.25, 1789.5, 1790.25, 1790.75, 
1791, 1791.5, 1791.25, 1791, 1790.75, 1791.5, 1791, 1790.5, 1790, 
1790, 1789.75, 1789.25, 1789.5, 1789.75, 1790, 1790.5, 1790.75, 
1791, 1791, 1791, 1790, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1791, 1791, 1791.25, 
1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791, 1792, 
1792, 1792, 1792.25, 1792.75, 1792.75, 1793.25, 1793, 1793, 1793.25, 
1793.75, 1793.75, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793, 1793.25, 1793.5, 1793.5, 
1792.5, 1793.25, 1793, 1793, 1792.5, 1793.25, 1793, 1792.75, 
1793, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.5, 1792.25, 1793, 1793, 1792.75, 1793.25, 
1792.25, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1792.25, 1792.75, 1793, 
1793.25, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793.25, 1793.25, 1793), V6 = c(1790.75, 
1789.75, 1790.25, 1790.25, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1790.25, 1790, 1789.75, 
1788.75, 1789, 1788.75, 1788.75, 1789.25, 1789.5, 1790, 1790.25, 
1791, 1791.25, 1792, 1791.25, 1791, 1790.75, 1791.5, 1791.25, 
1790.5, 1790.25, 1790, 1789.75, 1789.25, 1789.75, 1789.75, 1790.25, 
1790.5, 1791.25, 1791, 1791, 1791, 1790, 1790.5, 1790.5, 1791, 
1791, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.25, 1791.75, 1791.25, 
1792.5, 1792, 1792, 1792, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1792.75, 1793.25, 
1793, 1793.25, 1793.75, 1794, 1793.75, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1793, 
1793.5, 1793.5, 1793.5, 1792.5, 1793.25, 1793, 1793, 1792.5, 
1793.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.75, 1793, 1792.5, 1792.25, 
1793, 1793, 1792.75, 1793.75, 1792.25, 1792.5, 1792.75, 1793, 
1792.75, 1792.25, 1792.75, 1793.25, 1793.25, 1793.5, 1793.5, 
1793.25, 1793.25, 1793), V7 = c(11L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 5L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 26L, 2L, 
3L, 15L, 33L, 26L, 25L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 50L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 56L, 2L, 21L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 5L, 11L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see there are some missing values.
For example between   01/04/2007 23:26  and  01/04/2007 23:28    we miss  01/04/2007 23:27

What i would like is just add a row  with time 23:27  and all other columns with the same value of previous row

In other words every days should have exactly  60 (minute) *  24 (hours) = 1440 rows
From 00:00  to  23:59

Comment: Alongside Ronak's answer below, you might also want to consider some of the vignettes in the `tsibble` package. These deal with filling-in missing data and irregular time series data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `V1` and `V2` to create date time, use `complete` to include the missing minutes and `fill` to fill previous rows values in the new rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(datetime, V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::dmy_hm(datetime)) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = 'min')) %>%
  fill(everything()) %>%
  mutate(V1 = format(datetime, "%d/%m/%Y"), 
         V2 = format(datetime, '%H:%M')) %>%
  select(-datetime)

#     V3    V4    V5    V6    V7 V1         V2   
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>      <chr>
# 1 1791  1791  1791. 1791.    11 01/04/2007 23:01
# 2 1791  1791  1791. 1791.    11 01/04/2007 23:02
# 3 1790. 1790. 1790. 1790.     3 01/04/2007 23:03
# 4 1790. 1790. 1790. 1790.     6 01/04/2007 23:04
# 5 1790. 1790. 1790. 1790.     4 01/04/2007 23:05
# 6 1790  1790. 1790  1790.     5 01/04/2007 23:06
# 7 1790. 1790. 1790. 1790.     1 01/04/2007 23:07
# 8 1790. 1790. 1790. 1790.     2 01/04/2007 23:08
# 9 1790  1790  1790  1790      2 01/04/2007 23:09
#10 1790  1790  1790  1790      2 01/04/2007 23:10
# … with 337 more rows
```

Comment: Wow, incredibly concise and effective code. Thank you!   
If i want come back to original separation between Date (dd/mm/yyyy) and Time (hh:mm) ?

Comment: Add `remove = FALSE` in `unite` i.e `unite(datetime, V1, V2, remove = FALSE)` so those 2 columns remain as it is. You can then do `%>% select(-datetime)` to remove `datetime` column.

Comment: remove = FALSE works great.
But V2 variable (time) does not have the correct time. Infact when there is a hole, V2 contains a time value that is identical to that of the previous line.

Comment: This does not satisfy the last sentence in the question.

Comment: What you mean Grothendieck?

Comment: It does not start at 00:00 and does not end at 23:59 and does not have exactly 1440 rows per day.

Comment: in the sample i entered above it is true, but for all other days it seems to works great.
Can you better detail the reason for your doubt?

Comment: I am very fascinated by the method used by Ronak, but I admit I do not understand it yet. While Grothendieck's logic is more familiar to me, Ronack's I find it difficult.
In order to understand better, I have set myself the goal of moving all times by 6 hours into the future and eliminating all lines associated with times ranging from 22:00 to 08:00.
I think I need to use the "filter" function, but I couldn't apply it correctly. 
Can you help me?

Comment: I think it is better to ask that as a new question.

Comment: Ronack is it correct to edit my question above or better open a completly new question quoting your code?  BTW I have found the way to filter row by hours but i have some doubts about moving time 6 hours into the future.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input data frame is `tdf` we convert that to a zoo object `z` and create the desired range `rng` of date/times.  Fill that in with minutes giving `mins` and merge it back with `z` giving `zz`.  Finally convert that back to a data frame `tdf2`.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(tdf, index = 1:2, tz = "UTC", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
rng <- as.POSIXct(paste(range(as.Date(time(z))), c("00:00:00", "23:59:00")))
mins <- seq(rng[1], rng[2], by = "min")
zz <- na.locf(merge(z, zoo(, mins), all = TRUE), na.rm = FALSE)
tdf2 <- fortify.zoo(zz)
```

Depending on what you need you might hbe able to use the zoo object `zz` directly in which case the last line could be omitted.